# log analytics to collect and analyse IIS Logs

Tags: azure, scalable, azure-log-analytics

I have Web API application deployed in azure cloud service. cloud service instance auto scale is enabled .  some time instance count will be 2 and sometimes it will be 6 based on demand. I want to collect iis logs from server. and also i want to analyse the IIS logs using log analytics.  kindly assist me.

Comment: Why iis logs, have you thought about using application insights?

Comment: application insight storage is  not available in australia region. so we cannot use that